# Typeless Nonterminal in Bison

Tags: c++, bison

From what I can tell, a Bison declaration is in the form
`%type <type> nonterminal`

Is there a way to define a nonterminal without giving it a type?

Answer (score 0):

`%type` doesn't actually *define* a non-terminal -- it sets the type of a non-terminal that is defined elsewhere.  Some versions of bison give you a warning for a `%type` with an undefined non-terminal, but others just ignore it.

You define a non-terminal by giving a rule with the non-terminal on the left side (before the `:`).